# Percent calculation and assigning to new column in the same dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am having spark Data frame like below :

```
+-------+----------+-----+
| Status|  date    |count|
+-------+----------+-----+
|Success|2019-09-06|23596|
|Failure|2019-09-06| 2494|
|Failure|2019-09-07| 1863|
|Success|2019-09-07|22399|
```

I am trying tp calcuate the Percentage of success/failure by date and adding result in the same pyspark dataframe. I am able to calculate by group like only for success rate or failure rate after creating multiple intermediate tables/dataframe. How we can achieve using same single dataframe without creating the new intermediate dataframe?

Expected output :

```
+-------+----------+-----+----------------------
| Status|  date    |count| Percent             |
+-------+----------+-----+----------------------
|Success|2019-09-06|23596| =(23596/(23596+2494)*100)
|Failure|2019-09-06| 2494| =(2494/(23596+2494)*100)
|Failure|2019-09-07| 1863| = (1863/(1863 + 22399)*100)
|Success|2019-09-07|22399| = (22399/(1863 + 22399)*100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [`window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.Window) over the column 'date' to get same dates together and then use the `sum` the column 'count' over this window:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.partitionBy(['date'])
df = df.withColumn('Percent', F.col('count')/F.sum('count').over(window)*100)

df.show()
+-------+-------------------+-----+-----------------+
| Status|               date|count|          Percent|
+-------+-------------------+-----+-----------------+
|Failure|2019-09-07 00:00:00| 1883|7.754715427065316|
|Success|2019-09-07 00:00:00|22399|92.24528457293468|
|Success|2019-09-06 00:00:00|23596|90.44078190877731|
|Failure|2019-09-06 00:00:00| 2494|9.559218091222691|
+-------+-------------------+-----+-----------------+
```